# L'uso dell'espressione "in base a" in questa frase è corretto?

Tags: word-usage

Ho ricevuto un messaggio di posta elettronica con questa frase:

> I gesti delle mani sono un modo perfetto per rafforzare ciò che stai dicendo, ma fai attenzione... poiché possono avere tanti significati diversi *in base alla* cultura.

L'uso dell'espressione "in base a" in tale frase mi è sembrato piuttosto strano, quindi ho cercato informazioni nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/base/). Ecco quello che ho trovato:

> Frequente la locuz. *in base a*, e più corretta ma meno com. *sulla b. di*, sul fondamento di: *è stato arrestato in b. a gravi indizî; sulla base delle ricerche fatte, si può legittimamente dedurre*, ecc.

A me sembra però che, nella frase precedente, "in base alla cultura" non significhi "sul fondamento della cultura", ma "a seconda della cultura" (le frasi seguenti nel messaggio rendono completamente chiaro questo significato). Perciò chiedo: l'uso della locuzione "in base a" nella frase precedente è corretto?

Comment: *In base a, sulla base di*: ( loc. prep.),***tenendo conto, sulla scorta di*** . Penso sia corretta, io la userei come espressione. http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/B/base.shtml.

Comment: In realtà c'è una sottile differenza tra *in base a* e *sulla base di* che non saprei spiegare. Ad esempio nella frase sopra non direi *sulla base della cultura* ma *in base alla cultura*. (forse è solo una questione di uso personale dei termini).

Comment: ***Ngram***  mostra  un uso piu diffuso di *in base alla*  rispetto *sulla base della* .https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+base+alla%2C+sulla+base+della&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20base%20alla%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csulla%20base%20della%3B%2Cc0 - scusa la serie di commenti, ma la questione mi ha incuriosito -

Comment: @Josh61: Questo è precisamente quello che afferma il Treccani: "più corretta ma meno com. *sulla b. di*".

Comment: Questo è un commento alla correzione di @FerdinandBardamu : La correzione va benissimo ed è impeccabile, ma forse aggiungerei che se è vero che le frasi interrogative in italiano non richiedono una marca sintattica costituita dall'ordinamento delle parole, è anche vero che a volte la ammettono. «È l'uso XXX corretto?» non è molto italiano, ma per esempio «È corretto l'uso XXX?» lo è già molto di più, mentre in una frase affermativa, a meno che non sia in un testo poetico o molto enfatico, difficilmente diremmo «È corretto l'uso XXX».

Comment: @DaG. Grazie. Sí, sono d’accordo _in toto_. Una domanda: una frase come «È corretto l’uso XXX» non si potrebbe immaginare nell’uso corrente come posposizione del soggetto con funzione di tematizzazione? Immaginiamo una frase come «È corretto l’uso del congiuntivo, ma non è corretto l’accordo al plurale»: sottintendiamo che qualcuno abbia chiesto lumi sull’uso del congiuntivo, e, in questa frase, «l’uso del congiuntivo» funge da «ancoraggio tematico» rispetto al discorso precedente. Sbaglio?

Comment: Credo che tu ne sappia più di me, @FerdinandBardamu. Quello che scrivi mi suona molto sensato; mi chiedo solo se in una domanda della forma “È corretto l'uso del congiuntivo?” sia all'opera lo stesso fenomeno che nel tuo esempio di tematizzazione “È corretto l'uso del congiuntivo, ma...”.

Comment: @DaG, non so, sono pieno di dubbi e lacune. La tua domanda è pertinente e calzante. Il mio esempio voleva calare la frase affermativa «È corretto l’uso di XXX» in un contesto concreto, ma non so con certezza se la posposizione del soggetto sia accettabile in ogni caso. Se non sbaglio, la _Grande Grammatica Italiana di Consultazione_ dovrebbe contenere qualche paragrafo al riguardo: non l’ho con me ora, ma quando la recupererò vedrò di riportare qui quel che vi trovo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mio parere è corretto l'uso indicato anche se la frase è piuttosto sgraziata nella sua costruzione.
Come da te giustamente detto "in base a" nel tuo esempio è assimilabile a "a seconda di", e non a "sulla base di". A istinto mi viene da dire che questo è l'uso più frequente, quantomeno nel linguaggio colloquiale.
Ti faccio alcuni esempi:

- In base a dove ti trovi
- In base a qual è il tuo braccio più forte
- In base all'umore del momento

Sono tutte espressioni accettate e che non fanno riferimento al "fondamento".