# Il vocabolo "informazione" può avere un uso "non numerabile"?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5473/707) ho scritto la frase

> L'uso dell'espressione "in base a" in tale frase mi è sembrato piuttosto strano, quindi ho cercato *informazione* nel vocabolario Treccani

ma il vocabolo "informazione" è stato poi corretto come "informazioni". Tale correzione ha attirato la mia attenzione perché nella mia lingua (in catalano, ma anche in castigliano) la parola "informazione" dopo verbi come "cercare" o "chiedere" viene usata come un nome "non numerabile", quindi è scritta al singolare. Il [vocabolario Trecani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/informazione/) sembra riportare esempi di uso di questo termine come nome "non numerabile", ad esempio,

> Per una più esauriente *informazione* sull’argomento si vedano i volumi ...

ma anche esempi in cui ha chiaramente un uso numerabile, come in questa frase:

> Per *informazioni* rivolgersi alla segreteria.

Per questa ragione chiedo: in italiano, è corretto/usuale dare un uso "non numerabile" al vocabolo "informazione"? Se sì, in quali situazioni viene usato come nome "non numerabile"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In «Per una piú esauriente *informazione*, si vedano…», *informazione* è usato nell’accezione di «[a]tto dell’informare o dell’informarsi» (*Treccani*, «[Informazione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/informazione/)»). I nomi che denotano azioni o processi in quanto tali, in astratto, non possono esser resi al plurale, per un’ovvia restrizione semantica.

Al contrario, nell’accezione concreta, *informazione* descrive il risultato concreto, appunto, dell’azione d’informarsi o informare, ossia una notizia o un elemento «che consente di avere conoscenza più o meno esatta di fatti, situazioni, modi di essere, ecc.» (cito sempre dalla voce del *Treccani*). In tal caso, la parola è numerabile.

Occorre rimarcare il fatto che la non numerabilità dei nomi d’azione, come *informazione* in *mezzi d’informazione*, *libertà d’informazione* e simili, è legata all’accezione astratta della parola. Prendiamo, ad esempio, *nuoto* e *nuotata*: sono entrambi nomi d’azione, ma mentre il primo non può essere pluralizzato in **i nuoti*, il secondo è normalmente declinabile (*una nuotat**a***, *piú nuotat**e***). Questo avviene perché *nuoto* si riferisce all’azione in sé, *nuotata* invece alle singole istanziazioni di quell’azione.

In quanto all’ultima domanda, l’uso astratto del sostantivo *informazione* è, secondo la mia esperienza, piuttosto inusuale e per lo piú limitato a frasi fisse, come le già ricordate locuzioni *mezzi d’informazione* e *libertà d’informazione*. Con verbi come *cercare*, *trovare*, *ricevere* e simili, che presuppongono oggetti concreti, *informazione* normalmente si considera numerabile, sicché si dice *cercare/trovare/ricevere informazion**i***.